# Why did my ceiling light fixture stop working after adding an outlet on the same circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, light-fixture

I recently added a receptacle for hanging my TV on the wall. To do it I fished a wire through the wall and attached wires to an existing receptacle that's at a lower level on the same wall.

This is a wall that separated two rooms so there is another receptacle on the opposite end. All white wires and a black wire were joined together, and there was a wire between the two receptacles.

After I added the new wires, the ceiling light fixture in both rooms is not working anymore. I can confirm the bulbs are good, and I also tested it with a line tester and made sure current is reaching the fixture (in the bulb receptor), but no light.

Any other ideas on things I could check?

Comment: You're going to have to provide either a better description of what you did, a wiring diagram, or both if you expect to get useful assistance. When you say "*All white wires and a black wire were joined together*". Do you mean you connected a bunch of white wires with a black wire, or you connected a bunch of white wires and then a black wire to something else.

Comment: Before your work on the receptacle did the switch that controlled the light also control the power to the lower receptacle?

Comment: no it didnt, also i checked the current at switch and it shows its getting there.

Comment: You probably actually were measuring voltage (volts), not current (amps). What kind of connectors did you employ? It's possible for a bad connection to deliver voltage, but not enough current to drive a light.